# Is undecidability of arithmetic a corollary of Tarski undefinability theorem?

Tags: arithmetic, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Arithmetic is undecidable, in other words the set of Godel numbers of theorems of arithmetic is not recursive, and so there is no algorithm/ recursive function to decide if a statement is provable or not.

The Tarski  undefinability theorem for arithmetic states that it is not possible to express by an arithmetic formula the set of Godel numbers of theorems of arithmetic.
But arithmetic formulas contain the set of recursive functions,  so this implies that the above set is not recursive.

Does all this make sense?

Comment: There are problems with what you wrote. It is not clear what you mean by theorem of arithmetic. If you mean a sentence in the language of arithmetic that is true in the natural numbers, then what you wrote is essentially correct. We have to make precise what you intend in writing "arithmetic formulas contain the set of recursive functions." Formulas and functions are very different things.  If you mean the undecidability of a particular formal theory, such as first-order PA, or Robinson Arithmetic, then such undecidability is not a direct consequence of Tarski's Theorem.

Comment: I precisely mean  Peano Arithmetic, by theorem I mean a statement of the language of arithmetic that is provable. About the rest I mean  that any recursive function can be expressed by a formula of arithmetic.
Please can you explain your answer in terms of what I wrote?
Why do you think you can't  derive undecidability of first oder arithmetic from Tarski theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: The Tarski Theorem says that the set of sentences *true* in the integers is not arithmetically definable. It says nothing about the set of theorems of first-order PA. And in fact there is a formula $\varphi(y)$ which "says" that $y$ is the index of a sentence and the sentence with index $y$ is a theorem of first-order PA.

Comment: I see, this was the point I overlooked. What kind of Arithmetic Tarski considered in his theorem and how do you define the truth of a formula in this context?

Comment: The usual mathematical (model-theoretic) definition of "$\varphi$ is true in $L$-structure $M$." The point is that it is truth in the natural numbers, not derivability in first-order PA.

Comment: Yes the point is that I ignore  what is  
the usual mathematical (model-theoretic) definition of  truth  in L-structure M ( I am not an expert otherwise I would have not asked this question). I learnt about the Tarski theorem on wikipedia. Is the notion of truth you mean related to the semantic theory of truth by Tarski?

Comment: Well, there are two versions, the philosophical ("Snow is white") and its mathematical twin. Up to the time of Tarski, there was systematic confusion between (or conflation of) syntax and semantics. Through the work of Tarski, and others, a firm distinction was established, with the definition of truth as a bridge. This distinction is essential for almost all work done afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move this off the unanswered queue:

Godel and Tarski are looking at different notions of "arithmetic."

> **Tarski**: $Th(\mathbb{N})$, the set of *(Godel numbers of)* sentences true in $\mathbb{N}$, is not definable in $\mathbb{N}$.

As you say, we get as a corollary that $Th(\mathbb{N})$ is not recursive. However, that does not immediately yield Godel's theorem:

> **Godel**: The set $Thm(PA)$ of *(Godel numbers of)* theorems of first-order Peano arithmetic is not recursive. (And this can in fact be strengthened in many ways.)

In fact, $Thm(PA)$ is [much less complicated than](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) $Th(\mathbb{N})$; the Turing degrees of these sets are [$\bf 0'$ and ${\bf 0^{(\omega)}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump), respectively.

Actually, if anything the implication goes the **other** way. If $Th(\mathbb{N})$ were definable then we would have $Th(\mathbb{N})\le_T\emptyset^{(n)}$ for some $n$. But we have $\emptyset^{(n+1)}>_T\emptyset^{(n)}$, which yields a contradiction since $\emptyset^{(n+1)}$ is definable in $\mathbb{N}$. See also [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118753/is-it-possible-to-prove-tarskis-undefinability-theorem-from-turings-halting-pr/118889#118889). *(I've phrased this as a "relativized halting problem" argument, but you could also recast it as a "relativized incompleteness theorem" argument.)*

---

That said, we can use Tarski to prove a version of Godel with some more work; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72062/what-are-some-proofs-of-godels-theorem-which-are-essentially-different-from-t/353900#353900), where a slight variant of Tarski's theorem (but via the same proof) can be used to show that $PA$ (or indeed a much weaker theory) is *essentially incomplete*, and essential incompleteness of $PA$ implies that $Thm(PA)$ is non-recursive.